# OperatingSystemMXBean is not a valid MXBean interface error when deploying on WebSphere Application Server

Tags: java, websphere, ibm-mq, rhel

When deploying and executing my aplication in WebSphere Application server the following error message is presented.

```
[6/1/21 17:44:24:958 CDT] 0000004e webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp notifyServletContextCreated SRVE0283E: Exception caught while initializing context: {0}
                                 java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.ensureError(J9VMInternals.java:141)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.recordInitializationFailure(J9VMInternals.java:130)
    at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278)
    at com.transform.cartridge.volpayreferencedatautil.VolPayReferenceDataUtilFunctions.addTimeLog(VolPayReferenceDataUtilFunctions.java:204)
    at com.transform.flow.logaudit.LogAudit.Custom3Activity(LogAudit.java:100)
    at com.transform.flow.logaudit.LogAudit.executeInternal(LogAudit.java:152)
    at com.transform.flow.logaudit.LogAudit.run0(LogAudit.java:115)
    at com.tplus.transform.runtime.AbstractMessageFlow.run(AbstractMessageFlow.java:157)
    at com.tplus.transform.runtime.volante.MessageFlowVolante$1.run(MessageFlowVolante.java:75)
    at com.tplus.transform.runtime.volante.DeclarativeTransactionalExecutor.start0(DeclarativeTransactionalExecutor.java:137)
    at com.tplus.transform.runtime.volante.DeclarativeTransactionalExecutor.start(DeclarativeTransactionalExecutor.java:113)
    at com.tplus.transform.runtime.volante.MessageFlowVolante.run(MessageFlowVolante.java:73)
    at com.tplus.transform.runtime.proxy.MessageFlowProxy.run(MessageFlowProxy.java:32)
    at com.transform.flow.logaudit_sys_debug_instr.LogAudit_Sys_Debug_Instr.Invoke1Activity(LogAudit_Sys_Debug_Instr.java:41)
    at com.transform.flow.logaudit_sys_debug_instr.LogAudit_Sys_Debug_Instr.executeInternal(LogAudit_Sys_Debug_Instr.java:82)
    at com.transform.flow.logaudit_sys_debug_instr.LogAudit_Sys_Debug_Instr.run0(LogAudit_Sys_Debug_Instr.java:53)
    at com.tplus.transform.runtime.AbstractMessageFlow.run(AbstractMessageFlow.java:157)
    at com.tplus.transform.runtime.volante.MessageFlowVolante$1.run(MessageFlowVolante.java:75)
    at com.tplus.transform.runtime.volante.DeclarativeTransactionalExecutor.start0(DeclarativeTransactionalExecutor.java:137)
    at com.tplus.transform.runtime.volante.DeclarativeTransactionalExecutor.start(DeclarativeTransactionalExecutor.java:113)
    at com.tplus.transform.runtime.volante.MessageFlowVolante.run(MessageFlowVolante.java:73)
    at com.tplus.transform.runtime.proxy.MessageFlowProxy.run(MessageFlowProxy.java:32)
    at com.transform.flow.volantepaymentenginestartofprocess.VolantePaymentEngineStartOfProcess.Invoke4Activity(VolantePaymentEngineStartOfProcess.java:77)
    at com.transform.flow.volantepaymentenginestartofprocess.VolantePaymentEngineStartOfProcess.executeInternal(VolantePaymentEngineStartOfProcess.java:325)
    at com.transform.flow.volantepaymentenginestartofprocess.VolantePaymentEngineStartOfProcess.run0(VolantePaymentEngineStartOfProcess.java:300)
    at com.tplus.transform.runtime.AbstractMessageFlow.run(AbstractMessageFlow.java:157)
    at com.tplus.transform.runtime.volante.MessageFlowVolante$1.run(MessageFlowVolante.java:75)
    at com.tplus.transform.runtime.volante.DeclarativeTransactionalExecutor.start0(DeclarativeTransactionalExecutor.java:137)
    at com.tplus.transform.runtime.volante.DeclarativeTransactionalExecutor.start(DeclarativeTransactionalExecutor.java:113)
    at com.tplus.transform.runtime.volante.MessageFlowVolante.run(MessageFlowVolante.java:73)
    at com.tplus.transform.runtime.proxy.MessageFlowProxy.run(MessageFlowProxy.java:32)
    at com.volantetech.volante.services.StartOfProcess.process(StartOfProcess.java:45)
    at com.volantetech.volante.services.ApplicationStartupListener.contextInitialized(ApplicationStartupListener.java:218)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1837)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:443)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:171)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:904)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:789)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:427)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:719)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1249)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1591)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:708)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1162)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:801)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$5.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2325)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5536)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5662)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2330)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:436)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:379)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:127)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:985)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:524)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1909)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean is not a valid MXBean interface.
    at java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getPlatformMXBean(ManagementFactory.java:469)
    at com.volantetech.volante.services.performance.log.LogTime.<init>(LogTime.java:23)
    at com.volantetech.volante.services.performance.log.LogTime.<clinit>(LogTime.java:20)
    ... 57 more
```

The server is a RHEL with WebSphere 9.0.5.5 and java openjdk version "1.8.0_292"
The application is developed so it takes a message from a message queue and processes them. The message queue being used is IBM MQ 9.1.1.0. The application is taking the messages but not processing them correctly. The error is presenting on startup and also on execution.

Any guidance would be much valued.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question,  but I do know that there is not a IBM MQ 9.0.1.1.  Maybe you meant 9.0.0.1 or 9.0.1 or even 9.1.1.

Comment: Thank you Josh, yes it's 9.1.1.0.

Comment: WebSphere is using IBM JVM not openJDK, and you cannot change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was resolved by installing and configuring java JRE version 1.8 at Websphere execution level.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the AppServer is using OpenJ9 while your application is being compiled with openjdk 1.8. Perhaps you are getting mismatch in the WAS ManagementFactory. Try "ps -fea" and check the jvm being used.